# Links to election nominations don't work after nominations close

Tags: bug, election, permalink

If you go to the election page for an election that's past nominations but still incomplete (for example, [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/3)), and then go back to the nominations tab, the individual nominations still have links:

[image: Screenshot of the link]

This link points to https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/3#post-49000, which will default to the current election tab (primary, in this case). Since the links only work on the nomination tab, this won't actually jump to Mark Trapp's post. Can the link point to https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=nomination#post-49000 instead?

Comment: The links are actually broken even during the nomination phase, since they *should* link to `#comment-49000` rather than `#post-49000`. And I bet they don't auto-open collapsed comments, either.

Comment: Still an issue, came to report it. Actually the link should be `/election/n?tab=nomination&all=true#post-12345`, the `all=true` is necessary to preserve links to candidates who didn't make the top 30 cut.

Comment: Related: [Inbox links break after nomination phase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135651/inbox-links-break-after-nomination-phase) (similar issue, but in notifications; not sure if still an issue.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moderator Elections functionality: voting UI, commenting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361979/moderator-elections-functionality-voting-ui-commenting-and-flagging)