# Inbox links break after nomination phase

Tags: bug, election, global-inbox

Even during the primary, users can still leave comments under the nominations.

However, the link just points to the elections page, but it doesn't specify the phase.

For example, the link to the last comment I received pointed to

> https://stackoverflow.com/election/3#post-10982188

while it should have pointed to

> https://stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=nomination#post-10982188

so it still works in the primary.

Comment: Also, unlike the rest of SE, comment links do not expand the relevant comment thread if the comment is hidden away.

Comment: Related: [Links to election nominations don't work after nominations close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121682/links-to-election-nominations-dont-work-after-nominations-close) (similar issue, but on "link" button from nomination post).

Comment: This has *probably* been fixed with the recent [revamping of the election UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361979), but I don’t know if any recent election has gone into the primary phase, so I can’t check…

Comment: @TheAmplitwist: Has anyone been able to reproduce this issue since then?

Comment: No, not as far as a I know, @V2Blast.

Comment: @V2Blast The [ongoing election on ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5) has entered the primary phase, in case you want to check if this has been fixed.